# HTTP Post request with URL as parameter

Tags: java, android, https

I need send https request to server using parameters one of them is URL:
I do next:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(APIURL);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url", "https://api/v1/pictureadress/id"));
 ...
```

And I got error when add URL parameter. But if I add other parameters, except url, like age, gender etc. I have no errors. WHat I do wrong?

Comment: Your url is malformed: `htpps://` should be `https://`.

Comment: it is not real url it is for example. And url is 100% valid, I checked it in browser.

Comment: Then the problem lies with the server API. Can you post the code that handles the data you are sending?

Comment: I don't have servers scripts. But I know that on other platforms all work fine.

Comment: As an intermediate step, you may want to build yourself a dummy HTML page that performs the same POST you need to perform in the Java code. This will let you test that the posting process works correctly as documented, and that you are not failing to pass some parameters, etc. It will also let you approach the backend guy with a clear demo that puts you in a better spot to ask specific questions or request a fix.

Comment: I resolved this issue. Just change "h ttps://api/v1/pictureadress/id" to "api/v1/pictureadress/id"

Answer (score 0):

I have no exposure to apache component libraries. But looking at the api on [BasicNameValuePair](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html), I understand that the input name and values are stored raw and not *encoded*. I fear that is the reason why your `url` parameter's value threw an error.  You may require [UrlEncodedFormEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html) unless already using to handle url encoded name value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public void postData() throws Exception {


 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.xyz.com");

 List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

 list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","ABC");

 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));

 HttpResponse r = client.execute(httppost);

}
```